how to apply slow-motion on a specific sequence?
I have searched on youtube tutorials how to apply slowmotion in a particular sequence (not on the whole rendered sequence) so obviously I found a bunch of videos explaining how to apply slowmotion in general but I have not find someone able to explain how to apply slowmotion on one sequence and let the other sequences on a normal speed, when I tried this on my own the "slowed" sequence had the number of frames going down drastically, here is what I did :
https://youtube.com/shorts/74Y8lvRvdcQ?feature=share
how could I achieve this so that it appears smoother/slower ?

what you call slow motion is rather a lower fps, to do that I would do a normal render from frame 1 to 100, when the fps is normal, then do a second render from 100 to 200 but go into the Output panel > Frame Range > and increase the Step value so that you have this effect

hmmm I tried to play with the numbers in the frame range but !i haven't find any slowmotion being applied

Are you sure that you are looking for slow motion? To me the effect is just a low fps, like 12 images per second or even less, try 6 for example

this is the exact slowmotion i'm looking for (in the first seconds of the video) : https://youtu.be/vO7hKivZmY8?feature=shared

You could accelerate your video clip in the Video Sequencer?
